# A proof of the Bernstein inequality 

Tags: fourier-analysis

A friend is looking for a clean proof of the following inequality of Bernstein: If $f: R \to R$ is a bounded function whose Fourier transform has compact support, then 
$ \|f'\|_{\infty} \le C \| f \|_{\infty} $
where $C$ only depends on the support of the Fourier transform. Any reference would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There is something not quite right with your statement of the inequality.

Comment: By the way, what sources has your friend tried? Does Google and then a search in the default texts (Zygmund, Katznelson, etc.) not do the trick?

Comment: There is a proof in
 Nikolsky, S. M., Approximation of Functions of Several Variables and Imbedding
Theorems, Nauka, Moscow, 1977. 

that seems to be unreadable. I think he has looked up Katznelson. 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Fourier transform of $f'(x)$ is $i\xi\hat{f}(\xi)$, which has the same support as $\hat{f}(\xi)$. So we can write $i\xi\hat{f}(\xi)$ = $i\xi\hat{f}(\xi)\phi(\xi)$, where $\phi(\xi)$ is a smooth bump function depending on the support of $\hat{f}$, that is equal to one on the support of $\hat{f}$. Taking inverse Fourier transforms, we get $f'(x) = f(x) \star g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $i\xi\phi(\xi)$. From the definition of convolution, one gets $|f'(x)| \leq ||f||_{\infty}||g||_1$. Since this holds for any $x$ and $||g||_1$ depends only on the support of $\hat{f}$, you get the desired inequality with $C = ||g||_1$.